# Deploy a Win10 image over several brand PC with Win8.1

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have a batch of HP Prodesk 400 G2 PCs that came with Win 8.1 Pro preinstalled. There is no COA sticker labeled on the UC with the key. However the key it seems that is built in UEFI.
After I boot for the first time I can activate the Win 8.1 which is preinstalled.
I'd like to make an upgrade to Win 10  until the free upgrade will expire.
I made a station with the upgrade to Win 10  with all the software and settings that I need and I tried to deploy that on the batch PCs.
When I load the image of the Win 10 that I made I can't activate it because I have to enter the new product licence key and I don't have it in a material form like the COA sticker.
The HP support said that I have to make de upgrade to Win 10 individual, station by station, which is a lot of pain to do it.
The HP support said that the licence key is built in the UEFI firmware so why the Win 10 image after a sysprep does not see it ?
How can I relate the built in key from Win 8.1 to the image with Win 10 ?
Any support is wellcome.
Thank You!

Comment: "I have to enter the new product licence key and I don't have it" - You can retrieve the license from the ACPI table.  You should do that.  "The HP support said that I have to make de upgrade to Win 10 individual, station by station, which is a lot of pain to do it." - Legally speaking HP is correct.  The license is technically not stored in the UEFI, its stored in the ACPI table, which can be accessed by the UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want imaging rights for Windows 10, you need to buy a (single) volume licence for Windows 10 Pro, and then use that image and key to install Windows 10 Pro on all the machines.

You cannot legally image OEM versions of Windows for install (unless you're an OEM and using sysprep to return them to OOBE state before selling/distributing them).

So you only need to purchase the one VL key, to get imaging rights.  The trick here is though, that you can only use the Windows 10 VL image on a machine that ALREADY HAS Windows 10 licensed to it (legally, and because you can't technically "upgrade" the OS (7 or 8 to 10) with a VL image).

So you actually need to upgrade them all to Windows 10 before you can use the VL licence to image them, which means you're still stuck visiting them all one at a time and upgrading them first.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the only way it could be done.
Since there isn't a VL key I had to activate each win 8.1 licence, than individual upgrade and activate the Win 10.
After all of this I cloned all the stations with the same image and than run sysprep to get to OOBE state. The activation was succesfull and from now on I'll only apply the image when there is a need.
Thanks for your help!